# Digest Authentication WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to communicate with a server using Digest Authentication. I have the following code.
This works fine in Windows 8.1 but with Windows Phone I get "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This seems to be tied to setting Credentials. If I don't set it I simple get a failed authentication response from the server. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 var uri = new Uri(url);
 var cache = new CredentialCache();
 cache.Add(uri, "Digest", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = cache });
 return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows phone has its own webclient in `using Windows.Web.Http;`
Just use that for windows phone and creating a cleint will work like this:

```cs
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter
{
    AllowUI = false,
    ServerCredential =
    new PasswordCredential(
    "Your base url",
    "Your user name",
    "Your password")
 };

 var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
```

I am using this in a windows phone app to authenticate against a web with digest auth. So this should also work in your case.